# tag cloud based on weight / order_id

Tags: php, symfony1, tags

I am currently creating a tag cloud that currently displays the tag based on it's weight, i.e. the frequency it has been used to tag articles.

Now, I have also, in the administration section, where I can manage tags, the ability to move tags up and down (using an order_id field).

What this means, is that I need a solution, where the tags will not only be listed in terms of weight, but also by order_id.

Is this possible?

Comment: The weight will be added to the order id ? Or does one have higher precedence over the other?

Comment: yes, it is possible, although noone here knows what exacly do you have in hands ..

Comment: Well i have 3 tables, content, content_tags and tags tables, in the content_tags table is a list of content_ids and tag_ids. So I just need to loop through, displaying the tag and then order by the tag count and also by the order_id field in tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ... COUNT(*) AS `weight`, ... ORDER BY order_id, weight
```

You can specify multiple expressions in an ORDER BY clause. This will order first by the user-specified order_id column, then for any tags with equal order_id values, by their weight.

Comment: select tag.tag, count(*) as weight from content_item_tag, tag
where content_item_tag.tag_id = tag.id
group by content_item_tag.tag_id
order by weight DESC, tag.ord_id ASC - this seems to work, now to get into Propel..